# I am new on coding. Can we write this setTimeOut code in a simpler way and call it?

Tags: javascript

I am learning to make a preloader. It is working as you can see in the link provided below, but I am not happy with it. Working code here.. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJGJYx
Is there any other way that this can be done?

```
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('.si-preloader--logo').addClass('si-preloader-logo--opaque');
      }, 100);

      setTimeout(function () {
        $('.si-preloader-line--one').addClass('si-preloader-line-half--height');
      }, 800);

      setTimeout(function () {
        $('.si-preloader--logo').removeClass('si-preloader-logo--opaque').delay(100).queue(function(next){
          $(this).addClass('si-preloader-logo--opaque');
          next();
        });
        $('.si-preloader-line--two').addClass('si-preloader-line-half--height');
      }, 1100);

      setTimeout(function () {
        $('.si-preloader-logo--wrap').addClass('si-preloader-logo-wrap--offScreen');
        $('.si-preloader-line--one').removeClass('si-preloader-line-half--height').addClass('si-preloader-line-full--height');
        $('.si-preloader-line--two').removeClass('si-preloader-line-half--height').addClass('si-preloader-line-full--height');
      }, 1600);

      setTimeout(function () {
        $('.si-preloader--left , .si-preloader--right').addClass('si-preloader-dual-zero--width');
      }, 2500);

      setTimeout(function () {
        $('.si--preloader').remove();
      }, 3300);
    });
```

Comment: what do you not like ?

Comment: Is this code okay? Can we not reformat it? I could learn form it too. Also, I don't think this is the good way to do this task...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little cleaner ;)

```js
let animation = {
  prefixClass: 'si-preloader',
  className(name) {
    return `${this.prefixClass}${name}`;
  },
  delayedIntroduce(time) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      switch (time) {
        case 100:
          $(`.${this.className('--logo')}`)
            .addClass(this.className('-logo--opaque'));
          break;
        case 600:
          $(`.${this.className('-line--one')}`)
            .addClass(this.className('-line-half--height'));
          break;
        case 1200:
          $(`.${this.className('--logo')}`)
            .removeClass(this.className('-logo--opaque'))
            .animate({ opacity: 1 }, 100);
          break;
        case 1300:
          $(`.${this.className('-logo--wrap')}`)
            .addClass(this.className('-logo-wrap--offScreen'))
            .animate({ opacity: 0 }, 300);
          
          $(`.${this.className('-line--one')}`)
            .removeClass(this.className('-line-half--height'))
            .addClass(this.className('-line-full--height'))
            .animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000);
          break;
        case 1400:
          $(`.${this.className('-line--two')}`)
            .addClass(this.className('-line-full--height'))
            .animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000);
          break;
        case 2200:
          $(`.${this.className('--left')}, .${this.className('--right')}`)
            .addClass(this.className('-dual-zero--width'));
          break;
        case 3000:
          $('.si--preloader').remove();
        default:
          break;
      }
    }, time);
  }
};

const times = [100, 600, 1200, 1300, 1400, 2200, 3000];

times.forEach(time => {
  animation.delayedIntroduce(time);
});
```

```css
/* Global */
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

body {
  color: #1b1b1b;
  font-family: "Circular", sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: -0.0125px; }

/* Preloader */
.si--preloader {
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100; }
  .si--preloader .si-preloader--left {
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%; }
    .si--preloader .si-preloader--left.si-preloader-dual-zero--width {
      width: 0;
      transition: 500ms width ease-in; }
  .si--preloader .si-preloader--right {
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%; }
    .si--preloader .si-preloader--right.si-preloader-dual-zero--width {
      width: 0;
      transition: 500ms width ease-in; }
  .si--preloader .si-preloader-logo--wrap {
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 25px;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }
    .si--preloader .si-preloader-logo--wrap.si-preloader-logo-wrap--offScreen {
      transition: 500ms top ease-in;
      top: -50%; }
    .si--preloader .si-preloader-logo--wrap .si-preloader--logo {
      opacity: 0; }
      .si--preloader .si-preloader-logo--wrap .si-preloader--logo.si-preloader-logo--opaque {
        transition: 300ms opacity ease-in;
        opacity: 1; }
    .si--preloader .si-preloader-logo--wrap .si-preloader-logo--svg {
      height: 25px;
      width: 168px;
      fill: #fff; }
  .si--preloader .si-preloader-line--wrap {
    will-change: transorm; }
    .si--preloader .si-preloader-line--wrap .si-preloader-line--one {
      background-color: #888;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      width: 1px; }
      .si--preloader .si-preloader-line--wrap .si-preloader-line--one.si-preloader-line-half--height {
        height: 50%;
        transition: 500ms height ease-in; }
      .si--preloader .si-preloader-line--wrap .si-preloader-line--one.si-preloader-line-full--height {
        height: 100%;
        transition: 500ms height ease-in; }
    .si--preloader .si-preloader-line--wrap .si-preloader-line--two {
      background-color: #fff;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 0;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      width: 1px; }
      .si--preloader .si-preloader-line--wrap .si-preloader-line--two.si-preloader-line-full--height {
        height: 100%;
        transition: 500ms height ease-in; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="si--preloader">
    <div class="si-preloader--left"></div>
    <div class="si-preloader--right"></div>
    <div class="si-preloader-logo--wrap">
      <div class="si-preloader--logo">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1230.43 309.59" id="svg-replaced-0"
          class="si-preloader-logo--svg">
          <path
            d="M619.18 225.21a57.16 57.16 0 0 1-12.12 18.38 51.69 51.69 0 0 1-17.34 11.49A54.56 54.56 0 0 1 569 259a52.23 52.23 0 0 1-20.68-4.18A54.37 54.37 0 0 1 531 243.17a57.06 57.06 0 0 1-12.12-18.38 66.18 66.18 0 0 1 0-48.46A57.08 57.08 0 0 1 531 157.95a54.41 54.41 0 0 1 17.34-11.7 52.33 52.33 0 0 1 20.66-4.18 54.72 54.72 0 0 1 20.68 4 51.77 51.77 0 0 1 17.34 11.49 57.19 57.19 0 0 1 12.12 18.38 62.81 62.81 0 0 1 4.6 24.65 62.78 62.78 0 0 1-4.56 24.62zM790.67 60a35.55 35.55 0 0 0 49.92 0A33.51 33.51 0 0 0 851 35.09a33.52 33.52 0 0 0-10.44-24.86 35.47 35.47 0 0 0-49.92 0 35.41 35.41 0 0 0-7.52 11.07 34.21 34.21 0 0 0-2.72 13.79 34.2 34.2 0 0 0 2.72 13.78A35.36 35.36 0 0 0 790.67 60zm-367 86.36a42.84 42.84 0 0 0-13.41-7.86 48.21 48.21 0 0 0-17.62-2.86q-9.74.11-21.24 5.08a50.12 50.12 0 0 0-24.41 21.46q-8.3 14.51-6.16 33.15L431.68 156a35.51 35.51 0 0 0-8.06-9.69zm800.13 9.52a97.14 97.14 0 0 0-19.63-34A89.54 89.54 0 0 0 1172 99.22q-19.22-8.14-43.86-8.14-23.4 0-42.82 8.77a107.37 107.37 0 0 0-31 21.14l10-23.22h-61.83L951 228.09h-2.92l-51-130.34H788.37V247l-6.49 4.94a30.39 30.39 0 0 1-19.22 5.43q-10.87 0-16.71-6.88a22 22 0 0 1-5.64-10.55 59.11 59.11 0 0 1-1.46-13.57v-81.83H773V97.76h-34.14V35.09h-54.73v62.67H684v46.79h.13v91.68q0 35.39 19.63 54.58a59.14 59.14 0 0 0 20.68 13.43 74.7 74.7 0 0 0 27.78 4.9 120.88 120.88 0 0 0 24.44-2.3 92.31 92.31 0 0 0 14.45-4.38h52V117l79.11 185.47h53.89l45.63-106c0 1.21-.16 2.39-.16 3.61q0 23.81 8.15 43.66a103.17 103.17 0 0 0 57.21 57.26 112.71 112.71 0 0 0 43.24 8.15q34.67 0 58.69-15.46a114.67 114.67 0 0 0 38.22-40.52l-45.53-22.56a62.49 62.49 0 0 1-19.42 21.51q-12.33 8.57-31.13 8.57a65.92 65.92 0 0 1-18.8-2.71 50.25 50.25 0 0 1-16.92-8.77 52.14 52.14 0 0 1-13-15 57.39 57.39 0 0 1-6.89-21.51h154.2a23.19 23.19 0 0 1 .4-4.7 28 28 0 0 1 .42-4.6v-5a131.53 131.53 0 0 0-6.67-42.58zm-145.38 18q5.42-18 18.8-28a50.13 50.13 0 0 1 30.91-10q12.53 0 21.51 3.76a48.22 48.22 0 0 1 15 9.61 42.84 42.84 0 0 1 9.19 12.53 35.47 35.47 0 0 1 3.55 12.11zm-774-30.85c1.55-2.63 3.24-5.18 5-7.69.55-.79 1.06-1.61 1.63-2.39.26-.35.57-.68.84-1 2-2.6 4-5.17 6.22-7.63a100.36 100.36 0 0 1 28.67-21.52l.07-.17-5.14-3.09a47.36 47.36 0 0 0-13.16-6 65.2 65.2 0 0 0-18.59-2.32 58.3 58.3 0 0 0-17.76 2.86 78.71 78.71 0 0 0-16.71 7.52 73 73 0 0 0-14 10.92 52.91 52.91 0 0 0-10 13.79h-3.34V97.76H196.7v38.39a97.81 97.81 0 0 0-28.35-28.78q-24.23-16.29-59.74-16.29Q84.8 91.07 65 99.22a101.23 101.23 0 0 0-56.81 57A115.45 115.45 0 0 0 0 200.11q0 23.81 8.15 43.66a105.63 105.63 0 0 0 22.55 34.45A101.61 101.61 0 0 0 65 301q19.84 8.15 43.66 8.15 35.92 0 59.95-16.51A114.15 114.15 0 0 0 196.7 265v37.41h54.73V201.66a73.61 73.61 0 0 1 3.55-23.3 58.42 58.42 0 0 1 10-18.69 45 45 0 0 1 15.67-12.39 46.73 46.73 0 0 1 20.47-4.41c1.13 0 2.17.04 3.22.07zM196.7 246.23l-40.88-17.72q-7.11 14.63-19 22.35t-29 7.73a50.76 50.76 0 0 1-20.47-4.17 52.61 52.61 0 0 1-16.92-11.7 53.46 53.46 0 0 1-11.53-18.38 72.34 72.34 0 0 1 0-48.46 53.47 53.47 0 0 1 11.49-18.38 52.62 52.62 0 0 1 16.92-11.7 50.87 50.87 0 0 1 20.47-4.18q16.7 0 27.78 7.31t18.17 21.51l43-17.9zm156.8-14.13a57.37 57.37 0 0 0 14.86 17 52.13 52.13 0 0 0 17.85 8.67 50.23 50.23 0 0 0 19 1.35 65.93 65.93 0 0 0 18.33-5q17.26-7.45 25.18-20.2a62.51 62.51 0 0 0 9.28-27.4l50.75 2.66a114.67 114.67 0 0 1-19 52.35 88.6 88.6 0 0 1-7.4 9.44 100.25 100.25 0 0 0 38 30.48 88.58 88.58 0 0 0 37.39 8.15q23.39 0 39.27-9.19t23.39-22.14h3.34l-3.34 22.53v2.09h54.73V98.21h-51.35v24.65h-3.34q-7.52-12.94-23.39-22.14t-39.27-9.19a88.64 88.64 0 0 0-37.39 8.14 99.09 99.09 0 0 0-42 36.19 140.57 140.57 0 0 1 11.76 21.75l2 4.6a28.08 28.08 0 0 0 1.44 4.38A23.16 23.16 0 0 0 495 171z"
            fill="#fff" data-name="Layer 1"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="si-preloader-line--wrap">
      <div class="si-preloader-line--one"></div>
      <div class="si-preloader-line--two"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I will definitly learn that. But, there is a weird bug. When you leave the tab and come back to it after 1 second or 1.5 second. The layout is messed up. It looks like the time is slowed on tab change. Can we pause the setTimeInterval on another tab and resume it when we are active.

Comment: "The layout is messed up" what does it mean? Nothing like that happens in my tests on the last chrome.

Comment: The layout is messed up. That means when we leave the tab and come after 1 or 1.5 second, we can see for the brief moment that everything is crunched on middle and doesn't work as it is supposed to. It's too fast to capture on screenshot but is noticeable. Anyway, the animation that I am trying to replicate is of this website. I like it so, I tried learning it. Here is the link. https://luckyduck.digital/
Is my approach good?

Comment: Unfortunately, such descriptions you describe in my case do not occur. If you want more advanced animations, you can use this library https://greensock.com/

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)